# Why AR callbacks are not triggered for `Version`s created by paper_trail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paper-trail-gem

I'm trying to do something each time a Version is created by paper_trail by setting up a callback on the same model but it does not work.

I'm using Rails v6.0.0.beta3 and paper_trail v10.3.0. I tried creating the Version manually (`Version.create`) and it works.

```rb
class Version
  after_commit :do_something, on: :create

  private

  def do_something
    p('doing something') # never gets called
  end
end

class SomeModel
  has_paper_trail
end

# creates both SomeModel and a Version but version's callbacks
# are not called/executed.
SomeModel.create
```

I expected `Version#do_something` to be called, but it never happens.

Comment: The issue here is that `Version` is not the same as [`PaperTrail::Version`](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/blob/master/lib/paper_trail/model_config.rb#L171) it looks like the supported mechanism for this is to create a module and pass that through [See Here](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/blob/v10.3.1/README.md#5b-configuring-the-versions-association) or creating your own class [See Here](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/blob/v10.3.1/README.md#6a-custom-version-classes)

Comment: @engineersmnky you were right, since I'm using a custom class I had to specify the `class_name` as `has_paper_trail versions: { class_name: 'Version' }`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> > The issue here is that Version is not the same as PaperTrail::Version it looks like the supported mechanism for this is to create a module and pass that through See Here or creating your own class See Here – engineersmnky
>
> @engineersmnky you were right, since I'm using a custom class I had to specify the class_name as has_paper_trail versions: { class_name: 'Version' }. Thanks a lot! – Héctor Vásquez

- https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/blob/v10.3.1/README.md#5b-configuring-the-versions-association
- https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/blob/v10.3.1/README.md#6a-custom-version-classes
  -